# How do you solve the integral $\int\limits_0^2\left(\frac{1}{2}x^3\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is the question I am stuck on:

$$\int\limits_0^2\left(\frac{1}{2}x^3\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)dx$$

The answer is supposedly $\frac{32}{15}$ but I don't know how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Plz also provide the context of the problem, what you have tried and where you got stuck. I have voted to close this question. Please edit your question to include details as mentioned above and if it is closed, I'll vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions where possible, instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed.  If you need some help formatting the math, see this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4):

This question can actually be solved without trig/u-substituition.

$\int_0^{2} {{1 \over 2}(x^3)(4-x^2)^{1 \over 2}dt}$

Just take $4 - x^{2} = t$ and you are done.

The form after this basic substitution is:

$\int_0^{4}{{1 \over 4}(4 - t)(t^{1 \over 2})dt}$

which is yet another elementary integral.

Answer (score 2):

Use the trigonometric substitution $x=2\sin{\theta}$ and then the u-substitution $u=\cos{\theta}$:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int 8\sin^3{\theta}\sqrt{4-4\sin^2{\theta}}\cdot 2\cos{\theta}\,d\theta=
16\int \sin^3{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}\,d\theta=\\
16\int (1-\cos^2{\theta})\cos^2{\theta}\sin{\theta}\,d\theta=
-16\int (\cos^2{\theta}-\cos^4{\theta})\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos{\theta})\,d\theta=\\
16\int(u^4-u^2)\,du.
$$

All you need to do now is integrate it, do a double back-substitution and use that result as the antiderivative for your definite integral. Can you finish it off?

Comment: Yes thank you so much that has helped a lot. I was struggling with the substitution but this has cleared it up!

Answer (score 0):

See this,

$$\Rightarrow \int_0^4 \underbrace{ x^3 \sqrt{1-x^2/4} dx}_\text{ Change $x^2/4 \rightarrow y$} $$
$$\Rightarrow 2^3 \int_0^1 y (1-y)^{1/2} dy $$
$$=8 ~B(2,3/2)= \frac{32}{15}.$$

Where $B(m,n)$ is Beta function.